# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Todo[] | Observable<Todo[]>'

Tags: angular, service, observable

im trying to create a crud todo application with angular and started to create a service for calling the backend

task.service.ts

```
getTasks() {
    // check if app is online
    if (this.onlineOfflineService.isOnline) {
      this.http.get<Todo[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/auth/gettasks')
      .pipe(
        tap((tasks) => {
          this.tasks = tasks;
        })).subscribe();
    
      return this.tasks;
    }else  {
      //when offline
    return 
    }
```

and I call this service from a TestComponent

```
  tasks ?: Todo[] 

  constructor(
    private TaskService: TaskService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTasks();
  }

  getTasks(): void {
    this.TaskService.getTasks().subscribe(
      tasks => this.tasks = tasks
    );
  }
```

Unfortunaly I got a bunch of error messages :(

```
Error: src/app/task/test/test.component.ts:24:5 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
24     this.TaskService.getTasks().subscribe(
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/task/test/test.component.ts:24:33 - error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Todo[] | Observable<Todo[]>'.
  Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'.
24     this.TaskService.getTasks().subscribe(
                                   ~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/task/test/test.component.ts:25:7 - error TS7006: Parameter 'tasks' implicitly has an 'any' type.
25       tasks => this.tasks = tasks
```

Is someone able to help me with this stuff?

Thanks in advance and cheers, philipp

P.S.: I edited the service to

```
return this.http.get<Todo[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/auth/gettasks')
```

This solve the last two errors.
But now I still get the error, that the object in the component is maybe undefined

P.P.S.:

```
  getTasks(): void{
    this.TaskService.getTasks()?.subscribe(
      tasks => this.tasks = tasks
  );
```

added a ?, doesn't feel correct, but fixed the errors

Answer (score 0):

Basically you nneed to always return an `Observable<Todo[]>()`

change your else branch to do something like so:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'


....

if(..){
..
else {
  return of([])
}
```